# flutter_background_service update event not fired when downloading apk from flutterflow

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

I've implemented `flutter_background_service ^5.0.1` in a FlutterFlow project and have incorporated all features like `startService`, `stopService`, `update`.

The problem is that when I download the APK from FlutterFlow (Developer Menu > Download APK), it does not fire events on physical device (service does not stop, updates are not received).

However, if I download the entire project code (Developer Menu > Download Code), open it in VS Code and then debug on real device, it works perfectly. From VS Code, it also works on Emulator without any issues. No code changes are done on VS Code after downloading the project. The device is same in both cases and same permissions are granted.

Has anyone encountered such issue before? Is there anything I need to configure in FlutterFlow project before downloading the APK?